# Transpose rows into column in unix

Tags: linux, unix, awk, solaris, nawk

I have input file which is given below

Input file

```
10,9:11/61432568509
118,1:/20130810014023
46,440:4/GTEL
10,9:11/61432568509
118,1:/20130810014023
46,440:4/GTEL
```

Output which i am looking for.

```
10,9:11/61432568509,118,1:/20130810014023,46,440:4/GTEL
10,9:11/61432568509,118,1:/20130810014023,46,440:4/GTEL
```

I have tried with awk command, but i am not getting desired output. can anyone help me in this?

```
awk -F"" '{a[$1]=a[$1]FS$2}END{for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' inputfile
```

Answer (score 7):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk 'ORS=(NR%3==0)?"\n":","' inputfile
10,9:11/61432568509,118,1:/20130810014023,46,440:4/GTEL
10,9:11/61432568509,118,1:/20130810014023,46,440:4/GTEL
```

EDIT: As commented by [sudo_O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001405/transpose-rows-into-column-in-unix/19001641?noredirect=1#comment28072383_19001641) and [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001405/transpose-rows-into-column-in-unix/19001641?noredirect=1#comment28080719_19001641), the following variant is **more portable**:

```
$ awk 'ORS=(NR%3?",":RS)' inputfile
10,9:11/61432568509,118,1:/20130810014023,46,440:4/GTEL
10,9:11/61432568509,118,1:/20130810014023,46,440:4/GTEL
```

Comment: +1 However you should use parenthesis with the ternary operator to avoid ambiguity *(will fail on Mac)*. I'd have written it `awk 'ORS=(NR%3?",":RS)' file`

Comment: Can someone please change their answer to `awk 'ORS=(NR%3?",":RS)' file` so I can upvote it :-).

Comment: @EdMorton you known you have editing rights right? http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Comment: @EdMorton And your edit wouldn't need to be reviewed either :)

Comment: @sudo_O and devnull - yeah, I just hate to change the content of someone else's post, other than formatting if it's bad. It's like combing someone else's kids hair... Upvote done!

Answer (score 4):

With `pr`:

```
$ pr -ats, file --columns 3  
10,9:11/61432568509,118,1:/20130810014023,46,440:4/GTEL
10,9:11/61432568509,118,1:/20130810014023,46,440:4/GTEL
```

With `args` and `tr`:

```
$ xargs -n3 < file | tr ' ' ,
10,9:11/61432568509,118,1:/20130810014023,46,440:4/GTEL
10,9:11/61432568509,118,1:/20130810014023,46,440:4/GTEL
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to do it with `paste`:

```
paste -d, - - - < file
```

Output:

```
10,9:11/61432568509,118,1:/20130810014023,46,440:4/GTEL
10,9:11/61432568509,118,1:/20130810014023,46,440:4/GTEL
```

Comment: could we loop over all the `-` to transform a column to a row?

Comment: @Amir: sure, but it make more sense to use `tr`, e.g. `tr '\n' ',' < file`.

Answer (score 3):

if each of your "data block" has 3 lines, you could do:

```
sed -n 'N;N;s/\n/,/g;p' file
```

if you love awk:

```
awk 'NR%3{printf "%s,",$0;next}7' file
```

Comment: Good to see three different options! Note that the OP wants a comma `,` between the joined lines.

Comment: @fedorqui oh... I didn't test the 3 lines... :( I am about to fix it with comma.. thanx for point out.

Answer (score 1):

```
> sed 'N;N;s/\n/,/g' your_file
```

Answer (score 1):

A short `awk` version

```
awk 'ORS=NR%3?",":RS' file
```

Shortened, thanks to iiSaymour

Comment: Shorted still is `awk 'ORS=NR%3?",":RS' file` but like I said on @devnull's answers you really should use parenthesis around the ternary operator for portability across all awks.

Answer (score 0):

One way with awk:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{for (i=1;i<=NF; i=i+3) {print $i,$(i+1),$(i+2)}}' file
10,9:11/61432568509,118,1:/20130810014023,46,440:4/GTEL
10,9:11/61432568509,118,1:/20130810014023,46,440:4/GTEL
```

It defines each field to be a line. Hence, it prints them on blocks of three.